# How to present gravity in 2D (Euler's method) without using any additional libraries?

Tags: c++, list, class, methods, gravity

My last question remains unanswered, but I think I'm kind of on a right way this time.

What I need to achieve is a model of gravity, in 2D plane only. I need to have a class of a celestial body, with positionX, positionY, velocity vector and a mass. I want it to work like that: everytime I add a new body, its mass and initial velocity (if set) have an effect on all the other bodies, affecting their position and velocity accordingly. I have been told that it's best to use a list for that and everytime I create a new object I'll apply a `move()` method to every other list element. Is that right? (clarified because of [o_weisman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2899478/o-weisman) comment, thanks!)

I've declared the class (not all the variables are there)

```
   class CBody  
    {  
    protected:  
        double x;  
        double y;  
        double mass;  
    public:  
        void move(double time, list<CBody> CBodyList);  
        CBody();  
        ~CBody();  
    };
```

but I am unable to come up with the right method how to exactly make the new list object's values alter the position (by `move()` method) of the previous ones and represent it in time.

Do you have any ideas? Basically what I want to achieve is that whenever I add a new object with given values (I'm using `rand()` right now, but I'll probably use `cin>>stuff` later) it triggers a `move()` method inside every previous celestial body and adjusts their position accordingly. The problem is - it's not a fixed state, it's happening all the time, how to define the time exactly?

Big thanks for any clarification!

EDIT: Do I need to decalre the list before passing it as a parameter in method? Above code causes errors in VS2010, saying that `C2061: syntax error : identifier 'list'` and `IntelliSense: list is not a template` even though I did `#include <list>`. What's wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the code-block suggestion, Shevliaskovic! Markdown is still kind of confusing to me.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `std` (you actually should be using `std::list` anyway). Also, it seems that a `CBody` needs a velocity vector as well.

Comment: and make sure that you have `#include`ded the `list` in this exact .h file, not in some 'common includes' like stdafx.h, and that you have them after the classic `#ifdef/#define/#endif` guardians wrong (if you use them at all).  Sometimes you can messup the 'common-includes' and force them to not be included at all, or have them included **after** your class definition. Having the critically-required  includes at top of each .h file and after the `#ifdef` guardians ensures that they will never be accidentially skipped.

Comment: I can't down-vote, but I feel this question is terrible. Not clear, shows no research effort and actually rather useless. You should be a lot clearer about what you are trying to achieve if you want help with your homework.

Comment: Well, exactly this. I don't understand it fully, so I'm not clear about it. I need to make a model of gravity, where I can add more and more objects, give them position, velocity vector and mass and everytime I add a new celestial body all other bodies change their movement based on the new celestial body in the system using force equation. I figured out that it's best to use list for this, but I have no idea how to code it further... I got stuck in this project, even though I don't even know C++ and I have no way to get out of this. I do apologize, o_weisman, if I looked lazy and incompetent.

Comment: And yes, I'm `using namespace std;` - is something wrong with that?

Comment: Thanks, quetzalcoatl, I have included ir both in main.cpp and in CBody.h and IntelliSense error disappeared, the `C2061` one still exists, though.

Comment: The problem with this question is that SO is a place to solve concrete doubts, not to take private classes. And you need to learn a bit more about programming before writing programs like this one.

Comment: I do agree, which is why it was practically my last resort. I do understand the problem mathematically - I just don't know how to implement it. I suppose it could be too much to ask, but I really have no other choice. The only programming I deal with is PHP/jQuery since I'm a webdesigner - I took this project thinking I could adjust my experience to objective approach and try to make something out of it, using internet, trial and error. The problem is, I can't, I'm stuck, I don't know what to do, at all.

Comment: Where I come from, the moon moves whether a new moon is spawned or not. Looking only at the math of it, the state of a celestial body at any given time consists of coordinates and velocities, so you need to store x, y, dxdt, dydt in the class. Gravity then links the position (x,y) with the change in (dxdt, dydt) given by the gravitational force between the considered object and all other objects (F=m*a=m*dxdt). You will end up with a system of differential equations for all x and y coordinates and all velocities dxdt and dydt, which you plug into the euler solver that you want to write.